# How are complex/imaginary numbers programmed?

Tags: python, numbers, complex-numbers

I am curious on how complex numbers are programmed like in Python's cmath. Is *i* treated similarly to a variable?

Comment: What do you think it would mean for i to be "actually" √-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most implementations of complex arithmetic, Python [represents complex numbers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/complexobject.c) by storing their real and imaginary components. Operations on complex numbers are implemented in terms of their components; for example, addition is performed componentwise, and multiplication is the standard FOIL multiplication you should be familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for answering along with giving a link.